# Pull and store json data

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=19149

Trying to extract numbers from the above link and place them into a cell in google sheets.

For example, the `907.4k` which is apart of `"current":{"trend":"neutral","price":"907.4k"}`

These change every day and the plan is to write a function to auto get the new one. Just need some direction on the how to grab that small bit. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you need?  The current price of always the same article?  Or all the properties of every object?  Please be more specific.

Comment: Well I want every object but I'm sure it's just a matter of changing a few words around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON objects have properties you can get by simple iterations, below is a simple example of how you could get data in a spreadsheet in a readable format :

Feel free to adapt to your specific needs.

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=19149";
  var JSObject = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText());
  Logger.log(JSObject);
  Logger.log(Object.keys(JSObject));
  var item = JSObject.item;
    var data = [];
    for(var key in item){
      var row = [];
      for(var k in item[key]){
        row.push(key+' '+k+' = '+item[key][k]);
      }
      if(row.length>0){data.push(row)};
    }
  Logger.log(data);
  Logger.log(item.current.price); // the value you are looking for ;-)
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks! is it possible to just have it output, say, 907.4k in a cell that I specify? I need to do calculations with the numbers so I just need the plain number of 907.4k and I need to keep it in a cell I pick, say, A1 or B25.

Comment: From the answer you can see the properties names, just pick up the one you need and use it to write its value where you want:  item.current.price it the one you need.

Comment: Where do you see item.current.price in what you posted?

Comment: the code says `row.push(key+' '+k+' = '+item[key][k])` which represent what is shown in the sheet... `item[key][k]` is 907.4k when `key`=current and `k`=price. You can write it with brackets or dots.

Comment: see edit in code please. I guess you might consider accepting the answer now ;-) thanks

Comment: But how to make just one cell = the 907.4k and nothing else?

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1).setValue(item.current.price)`